# System Identification in a closed-loop feedback system

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

I have an unstable system that doesn't have a useable output when open-loop excitation is applied.

Subsequently I've used a controller to control its output. I want to use the system identification tool on MATLAB, but don't know how to calculate the open-loop input to the plant for a closed-loop system.

All the reading material is advanced and theoretical and has largely gone over my head. 
Can anyone explain how this open-loop plant input can be derived from known parameters of the controller and the plant output?

Comment: What's this stuff that you call "open-loop input" ?

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr 'u'

Answer (score 1):

Closed loop:
$$H(s) =\dfrac{F(s)}{1+F(s)}$$
where F(s) is function of the open loop system. Now if you have a controller C(s) in series with the system this becomes:
$$H(s) =\dfrac{F(s)\cdot C(s)}{1+F(s)\cdot C(s)}$$

You have to solve F(s) from known C(s) and H(s).